# Having better control on captions in two languages under each image

Tags: floats, captions, languages

I need to insert two captions (in polish and exactly the same translated into english) under **each** of the figures and above **each** of the tables in my document.

Once captions were defined I would like to have control whether only one or both captions will be displayed in the whole document through boolean variable.

What is the most elegant / smart way to do that?

---

**EDIT**

According to suggestions in comments, I used `bicaption` to define two captions.[image: two captions]

```
\usepackage{polski}
 \usepackage[english, polish]{babel} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[lang=english]{bicaption}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{Einrad}

    \bicaption{Polish caption here with special letters: ĄĆŹŚÓŁ}{English caption just below}

    \label{Fig:FIgBicycle}
\end{figure}
```

However, I don't like:

- that I needed to use `babel` to have properly labelled captions ("Rysunek" for polish and "Figure" for english), because in my document I'm already using many packages and I wish to avoid potential conflicts,
- the big space between two captions,
- that I can't see an option to control whether only the first, second or both captions were displayed

---

**EDIT 2**

Minimal Working Example:

```
%\documentclass[review,authoryear]{elsarticle}
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{mwbk}

\usepackage{polski}
 \usepackage[english, polish]{babel} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[lang=english]{bicaption}

\usepackage{graphicx,float,multirow}
\graphicspath{ {figures/} }

\usepackage[caption = false]{subfig}
\usepackage{lineno,hyperref,amsmath}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

\linespread{2}

\begin{document}

\linenumbers

\section{Some text}

\subsection{Some subsection}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin vulputate nisi dolor, vitae eleifend sem vehicula a. Nulla libero mi, scelerisque et dapibus at.

\begin{figure}[H]
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{Einrad}

    \bicaption{Polish caption here with special letters: ĄĆŹŚÓŁ}{English caption just below}

    \label{Fig:FIgBicycle}
\end{figure}


\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \bicaption{Polish caption here with special letters: ĄĆŹŚÓŁ}{English caption just below}
    \label{my-label}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
        \hline
        1st col   & 2nd col \\ \hline
        some text & ---     \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Take a look at the [`bicaption`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/bicaption) package.

Comment: which document class you use? `memoir` have this capability.

Comment: In document that I used to insert an example figure with caption here, I used `elsarticle` class, but in document within I need to use multiple captions, I use `mwbk` document class.

Comment: Well, yes, with `\linespread{2}` you introduce a large space between any two lines - that is just what you see between the two captions. Can you elaborate on what you want to achieve with `\linespread{2}` such that we can think of a solution for both wishes?

Comment: OK, I think that it might be actually expected by the publisher (if they need such spread between all lines). So, please ignore it, but, I just noticed that bicaptions provides warnings when I change the documentclass to mbwk (which is the class that I will use in my document that needs two captions): `\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{mwbk}`

Comment: Warning: Unsupported document class (or package) detected, usage of the caption package is not recommended. See the caption package documentation for explanation.

Comment: Regarding the requested boolean switch: `\captionsetup{bi-lang=first}` will only typeset the 1st language, and `\captionsetup{bi-lang=second}` will only typeset the 2nd language of the caption headings.